# How to ask "What do you need for...?"

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique

I know I could say "Qu'est-ce qu'il te faut pour X ?" but what if I want to use *avoir besoin de* ?

Would it be *Qu'est-ce que tu as besoin de pour ... ?* or is there an *en* in there, or should it start *De quoi est-ce tu as besoin pour...?*

Also, which is more idiomatic this way, if either ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to say "What do you need for ...":

> — De quoi as-tu besoin pour X ? (a bit formal)
>   — De quoi est-ce que t'as besoin pour X ? (a bit massive)
>   — T'as besoin de quoi pour X ? (familiar and most common)
>   — De quoi t'as besoin pour X ? (familiar)
>   — Dis-moi de quoi t'as besoin pour X. (familiar and not a question, may differ from what you asked for)

**Note**
X must be an action, something like "préparer le repas", "pouvoir avancer"...

**EDIT (cf comments)**
First, "Il te faut que je..." is ungrammatical. You can say "Il te faut [du pain]" or "Il faut que je [parte]", but you can't mix them.
So even "Qu'est-ce qu'il te faut que je  avant que...." is ungrammatical, the closest is:

> Qu'est-ce qu'il faut que je te fasse avant que... (but be careful, it sounds a bit sexual)

or

> Qu'est-ce qu'il te faut avant que... (but "je" is excluded from it... you may add it right before)

to be clear :

> Je peux t'aider ? Qu'est-ce qu'il te faut avant que... ?

In a sentence like "What do you need me to do before you can leave", the only way I see is this:

> — Qu'as-tu besoin venant de moi avant de partir ? (a bit massive...)

But if you remove the "besoin" constraint, you would say something like:

> — Qu'est-ce que tu veux que je fasse avant que tu partes ?
>   — Qu'est-ce que je peux faire (pour toi) avant que tu partes ?

Comment: One other thing-- what if it's an action ? E.g. "What do you need me to do before you can leave?" using *avoir besoin*...."T'as besoin de....qqch...avant que tu puisses partir?" I know I could say *Qu'est-ce qu'il te faut que je <action> avant que....* but I'm curious how to do it with *besoin*. Actually, is that right? Google turns up no sentences with "Il te faut que."

Comment: @Aerovistae I edited my answer to reply

Comment: Thank you! Very clear. I hate it when you can't directly translate a sentence, though. Very annoying when there is simply no way to say something in the other language.

Comment: I thought «de quoi» usually became «dont»?

Comment: Not really, no. For details on the difference between them, I would suggest posting a new question. But then again, I would also suggest toning down your SO profile so it sounds less like you're bragging about what an amazing clarinet player and martial artist you are. So take these things with a grain of salt.